# Have a method handle two types of lists

Tags: c#

I have a ClassAAA, that contains two properties:

```
ClassAAA 
{
    public string PropertyX {get;set;}
    public string PropertyY {get;set;}
}
```

And a separate ClassBBB, that has the same properties and an additional one:

```
ClassBBB 
{
    public string PropertyX {get;set;}
    public string PropertyY {get;set;}
    public string PropertyZ {get;set;}
}
```

Let's say I initialize both correctly and assume that there are items in it:

```
var aaa = new List<ClassAAA>;
...
var bbb = new List<ClassBBB>;
...
```

On both lists I have to execute the same logic, like:

```
List<ClassAAA> Manipulate(List<ClassAAA> list)
{
    return list.Where(l => PropertyX == ...).ToList();
}
List<ClassBBB> Manipulate(List<ClassBBB> list)
{
    return list.Where(l => PropertyX == ...).ToList();
}
```

The code of both `Manipulate` methods is identical, but I have to duplicate it because they are based on different objects.

The question is: how would you avoid duplication of logic in this case? Ideally there would be one `Manipulate` method that works with both types of lists, but how?

PS - also assume that I would like to avoid the use of reflection.

**EDIT**

Thank you all, the missing link was actually the use of `IEnumerable`, this is a working solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aaa = new List<ClassAAA>();
        aaa = Manipulate(aaa).Cast<ClassAAA>().ToList();
    }        

    public static IEnumerable<IHaveProperties> Manipulate(IEnumerable<IHaveProperties> list)
    {
        return list;
    }
}

public interface IHaveProperties
{
    string PropertyX { get; set; }
    string PropertyY { get; set; }
}

public class ClassAAA : IHaveProperties
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
    public string PropertyY { get; set; }
}

public class ClassBBB : IHaveProperties
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
    public string PropertyY { get; set; }
    public string PropertyZ { get; set; }
}
```

It also works without an interface, and by letting ClassBBB inherit from ClassAAA.

Comment: You could let ClassBBB inherit from ClassAAA

Comment: Is there some kind of existing relationship between the two classes? Is `ClassBBB` just a more detailed instance of `ClassAAA`? If so, then you could think about inheritance (i. e. deriving `ClassBBB` from `ClassAAA`) and let your method operate on the base type.

Comment: With inheritance, it would mean that you need to pass a List<ClassAAA> to a List<BaseClass>, but then the compiler complains that it cannot cast  List<ClassAAA> to  List<BaseClass>.

Comment: No, you can declare your method as `Manipulate<T>(List<T> list) where T : ClassAAA` and pass in a `List<ClassBBB>` if `ClassBBB` inherits from `ClassAAA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - define an interface and implement it with your classes:

```
public interface IHaveProperties
{
    string PropertyX { get; set; }
    string PropertyY { get; set; }
}

public class ClassAAA: IHaveProperties
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
    public string PropertyY { get; set; }
}

public class ClassBBB : IHaveProperties
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
    public string PropertyY { get; set; }
    public string PropertyZ {get;set;}
}
```

2 - Define Manipulate method:

```
IEnumerable<IHaveProperties> Manipulate(IEnumerable<IHaveProperties> list)
{
    return list;
}
```

**Note!** You should use IEnumerable here, not the List as IEnumerable is covariant so it would allow you to accept derived type values inside the collection.

3 - Use it like:

```
Manipulate(new List<ClassAAA>());
```

For additional information read about [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Ah I think the use of IEnumerable may be the thing I was looking for, I'll try it!

Comment: Just a point of pedantry:  Classes don't _inherit_ interfaces, they _implement_ them.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway agree. It hurts my eyes too. I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two options: if `ClassBBB` is an extention to `ClassAAA`, have `ClassBBB` inherit from `ClassAAA`:

```
class ClassAAA 
{
    public string PropertyX {get;set;}
    public string PropertyY {get;set;}
}

class ClassBBB : ClassAAA
{
    public string PropertyZ {get;set;}
}
```

Then just define one `Manipulate` method to work with `IEnumerable<ClassAAA>` objects:

```
List<ClassAAA> Manipulate(IEnumerable<ClassAAA> list)
{
    return list.Where(l => PropertyX == ...).ToList();
}
```

`IEnumerable` is defined using `out T` rather than just `T`, which allows covariance i.e. the generic argument can be a subclass.

As `ClassBBB` inherits from `ClassAAA`, you can use the same method for both. This will compile:

```
var newList = Manipulate(new List<ClassBBB>());
```

If `ClassAAA` and `ClassBBB` are very different, then have them implement an interface:

```
interface IAnInterface
{
    string PropertyX {get;set;}
    string PropertyY {get;set;}
}

class ClassAAA : IAnInterface
{
    public string PropertyX {get;set;}
    public string PropertyY {get;set;}
}

class ClassBBB : IAnInterface
{
    public string PropertyX {get;set;}
    public string PropertyY {get;set;}
    public string PropertyZ {get;set;}
}
```

Then define a generic `Manipulate` method:

```
List<T> Manipulate(List<T> list) where T : IAnInterface
{
    return list.Where(l => PropertyX == ...).ToList();
}
```

And use as follows:

```
var newList = Manipulate(new List<ClassBBB>());
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add `: ClassAAA` to `ClassBBB` in your first example